# Swipe ViewPager2 fragment from DrawerLayout Activity Programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-viewpager2

**Hi everyone,**

I have a Activity with a DrawerLayout -> Inside a FrameLayout for change view (Fragment)

My **ViewPagerFragment** have **TabAdapter** with 2 **Fragment** and **TabLayout**

I have a **ViewPagerFragment** with currentItem at 0 and another **ViewPagerFragment2** with currentItem at 1

**¿I can use only one and change it from activity?**

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Question seems unclear to me , what is that you want to achieve and what problems are you facing , please underline those

Comment: how i can to change viewpager2 tab programatically, from activity drawerlayout. my viewpager2 (fragment)